# 3 lavfi with different times and text complex filters

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello guys i want to have 3 lavfi:
1 at the start with black color with duration 1s
1 in the middle with 4 seconds duration
1 at the end with black color with duration 1s

The thing is that those 3 lavfi overlap eachother for 5 seconds, i cannot see the white lavfi in the middle, i tried to concatenate them but no use. Am i missing something?

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480 -ss 0 -t 1 -f lavfi -i color=c=0xFFFFFF:d=4.23:s=640x480 -ss 1 -t 4.23 -f lavfi -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480 -ss 4.23 -t 5.23  -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -filter_complex " [0:v:0][1:v:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1[v] " -format hls -sn -hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_flags split_by_time -hls_playlist_type event -g 4 -r 25 -map "[v]" output/index.m3u8`

Also how can i add inside complex filter transitions between inputs?

---

@Gyan thank you, it's working with `d` inside the filter;
concating those 3 works with `[0:v:0][1:v:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1[v]`. 
But how do I target each input and add draw text to it?

```
[0:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=2[0:v];\n' +
      '          [1:v]drawtext=fontfile=../../preview/fonts/tangerine-regular.ttf\n' +
      "            :text='In Loving Memory'\n" +
      '            :fontcolor=0x000000\n' +
      '            :fontsize=42\n' +
      '            :x=(w-text_w)/2\n' +
      '            :y=(h-text_h)/2 - text_h/2[1:v];\n' +
      '          [2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=2[2:v]; [0:v:0][1:v:0][2:v:0]concat=n=3:v=1[v]
```

I tried this but I get this:

```
'[Parsed_fade_0 @ 0x7fd4a500f300] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffee89c61d8] Picture size 0x0 is invalid\n' +
      'Error reinitializing filters!\n' +
      'Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument\n' +
      'Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0\n'`` +
```

Answer (score 0):

Seek and duration for an input go before that input.

`-f lavfi -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480 -ss 0 -t 1 -f lavfi -i color=c=0xFFFFFF:d=4.23:s=640x480 -ss 1 -t 4.23 -f lavfi -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480 -ss 4.23 -t 5.23`

==>

`-f lavfi -ss 0 -t 1 -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480 -f lavfi -ss 1 -t 4.23 -i color=c=0xFFFFFF:d=4.23:s=640x480 -f lavfi -ss 4.23 -t 5.23 -i color=c=0x000000:s=640x480`

That's the syntax mostly sorted. However, the semantics don't make sense.

For the color filter, seek doesn't make any sense since it's a static stream of a solid color. But even if it did, the results will be unexpected.

In `-ss 1 -t 4.23 -i color=c=0xFFFFFF:d=4.23:s=640x480`, the total duration specified in the filter itself is 4.23 seconds. So, if one starts from 1 second, the filter will only send out 3.23 seconds of frames. For color filter, best to just use `d` inside the filter, and avoid `ss/t`.